# Override default _get_for_dict() for ndb Property

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-datastore

i'm having a hard time changing the default _get_for_dict() Method.
This is what my code looks at the moment:

```
class ImageProperty(ndb.BlobKeyProperty):

    def _get_for_dict(self, entity):
        value = super(ImageProperty, self)._get_for_dict(entity)
        if value:
            return images.get_serving_url(value)
        else:
            return None
```

I'm not that much into the concepts for overriding methods, and having trouble with ndb iself...
Basically what I want to do: Store my Datastore Key as a BlobKeyProperty, but when retrieving it as a dict I want to get the image serving url.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but I *think* that this would be better as a `_from_base_type` hook:

```
class ImageProperty(ndb.BlobKeyProperty):
    def _from_base_type(self, value):
        return images.get_serving_url(value)
```

If I understand the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/subclassprop) correctly, this API "stacks" so you don't need to call the `_from_base_type` on the super class (`BlobKeyProperty`).  I guess `ndb` [handles that for you](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datastore-ndb-python/blob/master/ndb/model.py#L803).  Personally, I think this is a bit weird for an API when `super` seems like it would work just fine ... But ... that's how it is I guess.